# MYSQL Select 5 records for the last 5 distinct records

Tags: php, mysql, sql, select, greatest-n-per-group

I've searched on here for a few different ways to do this, but can't quite get this to work.  Basically, I have a table with a record of images added to a website. Each image is put into this table.  I want to grab the first 5 images from each distinct Added field.

So, the table may look like this:

```
ID  File    Folder  Added
----------------------------------
13  13.jpg  Event3  20130830
12  12.jpg  Event3  20130830
11  11.jpg  Event3  20130830
10  10.jpg  Event3  20130830
9   9.jpg   Event3  20130830
8   8.jpg   Event2  20130701
7   7.jpg   Event2  20130701
6   6.jpg   Event2  20130701
5   5.jpg   Event2  20130701
4   4.jpg   Event1  20130615
3   3.jpg   Event1  20130615
2   2.jpg   Event1  20130615
1   1.jpg   Event1  20130615
```

And I want the return to be like this:

```
ID  File    Folder  Added
----------------------------------
13  13.jpg  Event3  20130830
12  12.jpg  Event3  20130830
8   8.jpg   Event2  20130701
7   7.jpg   Event2  20130701
4   4.jpg   Event1  20130615
3   3.jpg   Event1  20130615
```

So basically getting the last 5 (sorted by highest ID first) images for the last 5 distinct 'Added' dates (again sorted for the most recent ones by the Added field).  Thank you!

**EDIT ---------------**

So it's a bit more clear... I have a table full of images I've uploaded to an image based website. For the front of the website, I want to have a news blurb that shows the last 5 galleries that have had images uploaded to them, and display 5 images from each of those galleries.  Each image that is in the mysql has an uploaded date ('Added') which corresponds to the gallery since I only upload images to a gallery one day at a time , and ID Number that auto increases with every image added ('ID').  There's a bunch of other fields of course, but those are the most important ones for what I'm trying to do.

**EDIT #2 ----------**

There's a lot of confusion over how I'm wording this, it's a bit tough to explain but basically how can I get 5 of the highest ID fields for 5 distinct Added date fields from a table?

I believe it has to do with this but it does not work when I run it:

```
    select TOP 5 * from (
    select *,
 row_no = row_number() over (partition by Added order by ID)
 from AviationImages) d
 where d.row_n <= 5
```

Comment: How are both `13.jpg` and `12.jpg` in your desired results?

Comment: Because they were the last images uploaded for that date of 20120830.  And I'm looking to get the last 5 images uploaded for 5 of the last distinct added dates.

Comment: The sample table above only has a small amount. The real table has thousands of images over the last few years.

Comment: This is a very confusing question... Even after the clarification

Comment: @DarylGill Okay, how about: How can I get 5 of the highest **ID** fields for 5 distinct **Added** date fields from a table?

Comment: Do you want one image per date? I guess no because I see 2 images per date in the wanted result. Do you want the last 5 images? I guess no because I see 6 and they are not the last 6 either. What exactly do you want?

Comment: @ypercube I want **5** images per unique date.

Comment: So, why your sample of wanted results shows 3 dates and 2 images per date?

Comment: @ypercube It was just a sample. I should have had it show 5 dates returned and 5 images per each date.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In many other DBMS (Oracle, SQL-Server, Postgres) you could use window functions:

```sql
SELECT id, file, folder, added
FROM
  ( SELECT id, file, folder, added,
           DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY added DESC) AS d_rank,
           ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY added ORDER BY id DESC) AS row_no
    FROM AviationImages
  ) d
WHERE d_rank <= 5          -- limit number of dates
  AND row_no <= 5 ;        -- limit number of images per date
```

In MySQL you don't have the luxury of window function and `OVER` clause:

```sql
SELECT i.id, i.file, i.folder, i.added
FROM
    ( SELECT DISTINCT added
      FROM AviationImages
      ORDER BY added DESC
      LIMIT 5
    ) AS da
  JOIN
    AviationImages AS i
      ON  i.added = da.added
      AND i.id >= COALESCE(
          ( SELECT ti.id
            FROM AviationImages AS ti
            WHERE ti.added = da.added
            ORDER BY ti.id DESC
            LIMIT 1 OFFSET 4
          ), -2147483647) ;             -- use 0 if the `id` is unsigned int
```

An index on `(added, id)` will help efficiency - and if the table uses InnoDB and the `id` is the primary key, then just an index on `(added)` will be enough.

Comment: The first one? No. Added query for MySQL.

Comment: THANK YOU! That worked perfect, and has ended my several hours of trying to figure this out. Works like a charm!

Answer (score 1):

Its not a pretty query but something like this should work

```
select pictures.*
from pictures
inner join
(
  select id
  from pictures
  group by added
  order by added desc
  limit 5
) as galleries
on pictures.added = galleries.added
order by pictures.id desc

where
  (select count(0) from pictures as ip where ip.added = pictures.added and ip.id > pictures.id) >= 5
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply @Ryan ! I tried out your code, replacing pictures with AviationImages (the table name) and uppercasing all the Added and ID fields since mysql is case sensitive... but I get a `'You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'where (select count(0) from AviationImages as ip where ip.Added = AviationImag' at line 14'`

Answer (score 0):

Your select query should look like this:

```
mysql_query("SELECT * FROM tablename LIMIT 5 ORDER BY ID DESC");
```

Basically, you select the last 5 results by descending order.

I do recommend you use MySQLi or PDO instead of MySQL

Comment: Thank for the reply!  Unfortunately, that only would give me the last 5 overall on the table. I'm looking for the last 5 images from the last 5 distinct Added dates. If I were to use that query it would give me back: 
`13  13.jpg  Event3  20130830
12  12.jpg  Event3  20130830
11  11.jpg  Event3  20130830
10  10.jpg  Event3  20130830
9   9.jpg   Event3  20130830`

Comment: I think what I'm looking for is something along the lines of this... but it give me errors:

`select *
from
(
    select *, row_no = row_number() over (partition by Added order by ID)
    from AviationImages
) d
where d.row_n <= 5`