# Mongo select last 5 values for each ID

Tags: mongodb

Suppose I have a collection with 2 fields:  id and timestamp.

I want to select the last 5 timestamps for each id in {1,2,3...}

How do I do this in a single query?

Similar to this [MYSQL Select 5 records for the last 5 distinct records](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18542749/mysql-select-5-records-for-the-last-5-distinct-records)
but in mongo

Answer (score -1):

If you have a parameter that you are deriving the last five entries from, such as date, and you let it equal 'idx' and assuming that you are sorting the values in ascending order:

```
db.yourDb.sort().find({idx:1})
```

In general, it seems that you will benefit from use of:

```
.sort().find ()
```

If you wish to sort the values in descending order, simply substitute '-1' for the value of 'idx'